# Return datatype from .env in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dotenv, phpdotenv

I want to have dynamic seeders based on my environment. (eg in testing I want so only seed 100 rows, whereas local it would be 10'000).

I've created seeder.php in the config, which is calling values from the .env file.

When I use the config in my seeder, it's returning a string on a value in the .env that should be an integer.
EG:

**.env.local:**

```
SEED_USER_COUNT=10000
```

**config\seeder.php:**

```
return [
    'user_count' => env('SEED_USER_COUNT', 10),
];
```

**UserSeeder**

```
factory(User::class, config('user_count'))->create();
```

The above fails to work and it appears that `config('user_count')` returns a string `"10000"` rather than the intger `10000`

Comment: can you just cast to int to solve that, like  factory(User::class, (int) config('user_count'))->create();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cast your variable to `int` in the configuration file

**config/seeder.php**

```php
return [
    'user_count' => (int)env('SEED_USER_COUNT', 10),
];
```

Call the configuration correctly with the prefix of the file

**UserSeeder**

```php
factory(User::class, config('seeder.user_count'))->create();
```

Comment: That works! Thanks (fwiw I was calling the config value correctly in the project, just mis-typed here).